# Why my ebook does not show words in my Kindle app?

Tags: amazon-kindle

I have 2 android devices. One of them shows the words. The other one does not. It also works fine in my PC. Please help.

Comment: Have the colors for foreground/background been set to the same? If you were to doubletap somewhere you believe a word to be, would a highlight reveal a word? If so, this would indicate merely a colorization mismatch.

Comment: All settings are the same

Comment: Possible repost your answer might be here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111936/can-read-books-in-amazon-kindle-on-lg-4g-tablet/111948#111948