# Can read books in Amazon Kindle on LG 4G Tablet

Tags: amazon-kindle

When I tried to read a book that I downloaded onto my tablet in Amazon Kindle, I can see the book, but when I go to the pages of the book, there is nothing.  I see the title of the book across the top of the page, but nothing is showing on the page itself.  Can read the book on my phone under Kindle so need to know what the problem is with tablet.  I have tried rebooting the tablet, but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you gone into your account on Amazon and registered the Kindle for Android app that you downloaded to your account. You need to do that before you will be able to view Amazon content on your Kindle for Android App. Try going to your account on Amazon. Then go to Digital Content. Then under Digital Management, go to Manage Your Kindle. Then, on the left side go to Manage Your Kindle and choose Manage Your Devices. You should see a list of REGISTERED KINDLES. Your Kindle for Android app should be listed as one of the 'registered devices'. All the ebooks you get from Amazon are coded to work with a specific device on your account. Yes, they can work on more than one BUT your Kindle for Android app must be registered on your account (where the book was purchased from) in order for it to be read on that device.